# Deductions from the graph of function and derivative

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives, graphing-functions

Given the following graphs:

[image]

knowing that the blue one is the graph of $f$ and the orange one of $f'$, at first glance I would say that $f$ has an oblique asymptote $y = m\,x + q$, with $m = 1$ and $q < 0$, due to the horizontal asymptote of $f'$.

On the other hand, thinking about it for a moment, I think it's wrong and a counterexample should be $f(x) = x + \log x$. Am I right?

If finally, assuming that in addition to the graph there is information that $f$ admits an oblique asymptote, $q$ could only be estimated roughly from the graph, right?

Thank you!

Comment: A horizontal asymptote suggests the possibility of, but as your counterexample shows, does not imply an oblique asymptote of the original graph. You are also correct that $q$ can only be estimated from the graph. Looking at points with larger values of $x$ will give better estimates.

Comment: @TomKern: Thank you so much for your confirmation!